# Android programming warning: skipped 314 frames

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For some reason, I have to change all my other Fragment class and other relative class to extends android.support.v4.app.fragment/fragmentManager/fragmentActivity

After I changed them, I found the application runs much slower than before and Android Studio showed a log: ***Skipped 314 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread***. What's wrong with android.support.v4.app library and is there any solution?

Such things happened when I skip from listFragment to an activity which extends an abstract class. The codes are too complex to show out

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong with android.support.v4.app library

Nothing, in general.

> is there any solution?

Find where you are spending too much time on the main application thread, then move that code to a background thread or greatly reduce the time that it is taking.

There are a variety of tools to help you identify where your code is spending too much time, including:

- [`StrictMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)
- [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)
- [gfxinfo](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html)
- [systrace](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html)

There are many [articles](http://www.curious-creature.com/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html), [blog posts](http://www.curious-creature.com/2015/03/25/android-performance-case-study-follow-up/), [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8m9sHdyXnE), [book chapters](https://commonsware.com/Android), and the like that can help you use those tools.